# billboard.js is not working in safari

Tags: javascript

I have a billboard.js script running on a simple php file and for some reason it works fine in FF and IE but not Safari. I checked source code it and is pulling the content but the scrolling feature does not work when you click. Can someone please help me. Here is the link to try: [www.luc.edu/test/cabplan/soc/test.php](http://www.luc.edu/test/cabplan/soc/test.php)

Comment: What's billboard.js, first of all?

Comment: @Carl Jacobson look into the source code my friend, it is quite easy to find.

Comment: Tell me @alpdog14, are you using the YUI3 carousel script?

Comment: @Christopher So's my name, thanks.  -- Cal

Comment: @Cal, sorry I didn't mean to add that extra "r" in there. Typo.

As for billboard.js, I am pretty certain it is the YUI3 ( http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/ ) carousel script.

Comment: actually it was a extra div causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an extra div tag